# Is there an alternative for this chmod command on Debian?

Tags: chmod

I'm trying to setup a chmod using this command

```
sudo chmod +a "www-data allow delete,write,append,file_inherit,directory_inherit" app/cache app/logs
```

apparently this does not work on debian.

Any clue on how to achieve the same thing ?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Where have you ever seen that command work? I've been around the block a few times, and have never seen such a thing.

Comment: I'm trying to setup the cache of symfony2 based on the tutorial http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup and I opened a bug here https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/374

Comment: @ErikA: http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/chmod/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Symfony documentation at [Installing and Configuring Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html) explains that if **chmd +a** is not supported, you can install the **acl** package and use the **setfacl** command instead of **chmod +a**.

Once you install the **acl** package, follow the directions at [FilePermissions#ACLs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions#ACLs) to enable **acl** on your partition. This will allow you to use **setfacl**,

Answer (score 1):

The command seems to be correct... ***if*** you are using a version of CHMOD which supports ACLs and a filesystem which does the same.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve the same thing witout ACL ?

Comment: Uhm... according to the article you linked, I'd say "yes, it's the example shown *exactly below* the one with ACLs" :-D

Comment: Well I was thinking command line wise

Comment: I don't know what the exact requirements are for this software to works, and looks like you don't know it so much in depth as well; since the tutorial you are following provides two ways of configuring it, one with ACLs and one without them for those systems which don't support them, I'd just stick to the tutorial.

Comment: And if you *really* want to use ACLs, you should make sure that the filesystem is [mounted with ACL support as well](http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/acl.htm)